# Could you tell me the differences between the standard libraries for fragment and activities and support v4?

Tags: android

I am using KitKat version to build an application which has a menu in the left and when you click in the option shows the fregment selected.

Now it is working but I wasn't clear the concept of the libraries, it is to say, I don't understand the differences using normal libraries and support v4.

Initially, I was using the standard library to set my fregment using

```
android.app.Activity 
android.app.Fregment
```

and the code to add fregments:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I decided to use support v4 in the activity because It wasn't working and the application stopped when I lanched it, myy code in the activity, and it is working is:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

Fregment fragment = new MapaFragment();

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
...
ft.commit();
```

the code in fregment:

```
package info.android;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapaFragment extends Fragment {

    public PagesFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The layour I use this layout (fragment_map.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I would like to know it is the differences between the normnal libraries and support v4. I DON'T NEED EXAMPLES, I SET SOME EXAMPLES OF MY CODE I USED.

I need understand to apply everything in future right.

Could you help me please?

Comment: The support library adds Fragments (and not only) to older devices (API level < 11). Still it's fully compatible with newer devices. So, it really depends on your Manifest's minSdkVersion to support older devices or not.

Comment: At the moment in my manifest file i have. Api level 19 as minimus and 19 as current

Comment: So. As you see, you don't need the support library at all. BUT I **highly recommend** you to make your app available to older devices, setting your minSdkVersion to **8** (**Froyo** still is the **1.1%** of the global market - and won't be gone before an year or so). So, you'll need the support library.